# php string replace $date

Tags: php, date, replace

After searching still problems with string replace
My `$date` looks like

Sat, 11 Feb 2017 11:33:38 +0100

I need only the date part (YYYY-MM-DD):

2017-02-11

Please can somebody help.
Thank you!
Best regards,
Roman

Comment: which php version are you using??

Comment: tons of similar questions but we still need to ask another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

`$date` is var name that contain like `Sat, 11 Feb 2017 11:33:38 +0100`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Best regards, JR

Answer (score 0):

use 
date("Y-M-D", strtotime($date));